# How to go about migrating from a 32-bit Ubuntu VPS to a 64-bit VPS?

Tags: ubuntu, 32bit-64bit, migration

I have a VPS that is running 32-bit Ubuntu server edition.  I understand that migrating to 64-bit means reinstalling the OS; how do I do this remotely?  Or do I need my host to do it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there isnt a simple way to do this

the easiest option i can see, is build a whole new server with 64Bit ubuntu and then installing the required software and transferring your configs and files from the old server to the new one

Comment: but that means getting a second vps, no?

Comment: yes that is correct, only for the duration of transfer

Comment: Thanks, actually I might go this route instead... rent a cheap VPS for a month, get it done, drop the second VPS.

Answer (score 2):

This is not trivial and may not be possible with the tools your host provides. Your best course of action is to check with your host to see if they can provision this for you.

Comment: it turns out this is the way to go.. they provide OS installation service; I can use their cp to make a backup, then download the backup to the new server, reinstall.  I guess I was looking for a way to do it without downtime, which is really asking a lot.  Certainly not trivial - I don't really understand the difficulty in just replacing all software and kernel with 64-bit versions, but I assume there is a reason why it can't be done that way.

Comment: be careful that backup isnt a full system backup which would put you back at square one or worse a broken system - the reason its not easy is due to the hundreds if not thousands of different dependencies that have to get updated between 32bit and 64bit its much safer to transfer the minimum required data

Comment: @anthonysomerset - thanks, I guess it makes sense.